# How I realize master page in Rails just as in .NET

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so,I am a beginner,I know there is `layout` in rails .

but I want a shared part that many pages will use,include all of the `mvc` other than just `v`
.just like the master page in .Net webform.

for example .every site will own may manage pages,and this pages will use a common left sidebar which is consists of a few menus.

how can I realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should read the [Rails layouts and rendering guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) to get an understanding of rendering in rails.

Rails provides layouts, partials and content_for blocks for rendering a view.

An example main layout to illustrate use of partials and dynamic content_for sections:

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
      <%= yield :breadcrumbs %>
    </ul>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <%= render 'sidebar' %>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main layout sidebar partial:

```
# layouts/_sidebar.html.erb
<ul class="sidebar">
  <li><%= link_to 'Posts', posts_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'My Profile', current_user %></li>
</ul>
```

The posts controller's `show` action view template which renders dynamic layout content for the breadcrumbs:

```
# posts/show.html.erb
<% content_for :breadcrumbs do %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Posts', posts_path %></li>
  <li><%= @post.title %></li>
<% end %>
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using nested layouts and partials http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Your application general layout is defined in the ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

As suggested, look at the link about and read about %yield%
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Enjoy